# Pivot chart - Planned vs Actual dates

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a set of data related to planned execution dates and actual execution dates for a number of tasks as shown below:

[image: Data set]

I've managed to create a pivot chart and table to show the number of task names at every planned date like this:

[image]

But I can't seem to add another line on the same graph to show the counts for the actual dates as well.

Comment: Wow, I can't duplicate your results.  The spreadsheet data does NOT seem to match the chart.  Please show all data (or less chart).  also include to code that you are using, and failing attempts for ActualDate-s.

Comment: @donPablo I've updated the chart. I'm not sure what you mean by code, as I'm doing this using the Pivot Chart tool. I tried adding the count of planned and count of actual to the 'Values' section but I'm not able to add both sets of dates to the 'Rows' section